# Is it possible to perform $z$ rotation in Qiskit with just $x$ and $y$ rotations?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, circuit-construction

Is it possible to perform $z$ rotation in Qiskit with just $x$ and $y$ rotations?

I tried the following:

```
from qiskit import *
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)

theta = 0.5*np.pi
qc.ry(np.pi/2,0)
qc.rx(-np.pi/2,0)

qc.ry(theta,0)

qc.rx(np.pi/2,0)
qc.ry(-np.pi/2,0)
```

The code is based on ([Realization of High-Fidelity CZ and ZZ-Free iSWAP Gates with a Tunable Coupler](https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.11.021058)) (page 26), but it seems that I do something wrong.

Comment: You should use `theta` more often, if not why defining it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decomposition they give is the following:

$$
R_z(\theta) = R_x\left(\pi / 2\right) R_y(\theta) R_x\left(-\pi / 2\right)
$$

Therefore, the Qiskit code would look like:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Operator
import numpy as np

theta = np.pi / 4

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.rx(-np.pi / 2, 0)
qc.ry(theta, 0)
qc.rx(np.pi / 2, 0)

Operator(qc).data
```

Which gives output:

```
array([[0.92387953-0.38268343j, 0.        +0.j        ],
       [0.        +0.j        , 0.92387953+0.38268343j]])
```

And we can see it is equivalent to $R_z(\theta)$:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.rz(theta, 0)

Operator(qc).data
```

```
array([[0.92387953-0.38268343j, 0.        +0.j        ],
       [0.        +0.j        , 0.92387953+0.38268343j]])
```

Comment: Thank you! Operator data can really persuade that it is reall Z-gate. But how to visualize it, like population vs rotation angle in paper? If I remove -Y/2 and Y/2 in qiskit the result will be always |0> on the Bloch sphere.

Comment: Be careful, I guess the Qiskit calculation is right, but the sign should be inverted in your 1st equation.

Comment: @Mauricio thanks about that!

Comment: @epelaaez is it possible to visualize the result of such rotation on the Bloch sphere? without Y/2 and -Y/2 the final result always 0.

Comment: @Curious, that's because the $R_z$ gate does not alter the amplitude of the states. I think that the $\pm Y/2$ rotations in the paper are exactly put there to do what you want as they make the phase added by the $Z$ rotation have some interference effect. So you can try adding the $\pm Y/2$ gates back on and plotting the probability of measuring $|0\rangle$ for many $\theta$.

Comment: @Curious it is not possible without a rotation to another axis. Think about it, $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ lie in the $Z$ axis, so the rotation does nothing to them (other than a global phase)

Comment: @epelaaez thank you so much for explanations! For now it is hard to imagine, that you change the phase of the vector, but it still in the initial position: I expected something like, I do X/2 and then "somehow" I do rotation around Z-axis like during dephasing))

Comment: @Curious maybe it is easier to think about it in regular geometry terms. Suppose you have the basis vector $(1,0,0)$ and you want to rotate it along the $x$ axis. There you can see that it’ll not move.

Comment: @epelaaez in this case the first my thought is that I can't do such rotation, but according to the paper in my posted question I can...

Comment: @Curious yup that would be correct reasoning. And if we are considering a single-qubit system, there would be no effect as we would only be adding a global phase to the qubit, which is undetectable. You may find [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/visualize-the-invisible-qubit-phase-e65c04f14969) helpful.

Comment: @epelaaez sounds fine, at least I think I get the point)) thank you so much for the link! it looks very "tasty" for learning!!